# Adding OnClickListener on ButtonSprite using andengine on Android

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm creating an app using the andengine for Android. I'm autogenerating some of the screens and need to set specific OnClickListeners to specific buttons.

I'm using `org.andengine.entity.sprite.ButtonSprite` and  `org.andengine.entity.sprite.ButtonSprite.OnClickListener`.

Each button has an id string so I had hoped to be able to create the listeners when I initialize the scene and store them in a HashMap. Like so:

```java
buttonListeners = HashMap<String, Object>();
OnClickListener ocl = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick( ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY ) {
                //Do stuff
                Log.d("Button Test", "Huzzah A");
            }      
        };
buttonListeners.put("play_button", ocl);
```

And then when I create the button just do:

```java
button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) buttonListeners.get(button.id));
```

This does not work. I suspected some problems in my HashMap so I created a class variable ocl2 identical to the one above, initialized it in the constructor and tried using it like this:

```java
button.setOnClickListener(ocl2);
```

It did not work either. Intent on making sure I wasn't just doing "it" wrong I tried this:

```java
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick( ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY )
    {
        //Do stuff
        Log.d("Button Test", "Huzzah C");
    }      
});
```

And this way works flawlessly. Problem being that since I autogenerate everything I can't use this method (at least not the way that I'd want to...)

Is this some limitation on the way that this works? Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get around the problem by using the following:

```
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick( ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY )
    {
        (buttonListeners.get(button.id))).onClick(pButtonSprite, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    }      
});
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar! This seems to be working flawlessly. My code will be so pretty now!